# MvvmCross and WP7 secondary tile

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, mvvmcross

At first of all, MvvmCross is just great. Working with them is really enjoyable.

I have a small problem with secondary tiles in WP7. I have a classic Master-Detail scenario and I want to do secondary tile for Detail (View / ViewModel).
So how can I create a secondary tile from ViewMode?

```
public IMvxCommand DetailPinCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new MvxRelayCommand<Detail>((d) =>
                    {
                        StandardTileData NewTileData = new StandardTileData
                        {
                            Title = d.Name
                            ...
                            ...
                        };

                        ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/Views/DetailView.xaml?DetailId=" + d.ID, UriKind.Relative), NewTileData);

                    });
            }
        }
```

This is just wrong in viewmodel, and of course it does not work...
Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mvx includes one example service that allows some simple live tiles/bookmarks to be added - [MvxWindowsPhoneLiveTileBookmarkLibrarian.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/master/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/WindowsPhone/Platform/Bookmarks/MvxWindowsPhoneLiveTileBookmarkLibrarian.cs)

This is currently only implemented for WP7 - but Android and WinRT bookmarks might also be possible using the same template in the future.

If you want to use the librarian service, you can try something like:

```
IMvxBookmarkLibrarian librarian;
if (!this.TryGetService<IMvxBookmarkLibrarian>(out librarian))
{
    // not much can be done...
    return;
}

var metadata = new BookmarkMetadata()
{
    Title = detail.Name,
};

var uniqueName = "DetailBookmark" + detail.UniqueId;

librarian.AddBookmark(
            typeof(DetailViewViewModel), 
            uniqueName, 
            metadata, 
            new Dictionary<string, string>()
                   {
                       { "detailId", detail.UniqueId }
                   });
```

This will call through to WP7 code which generates the TileData and a Xaml Uri for the  tile - to understand how the uri is generated, see the code around `GetXamlUriFor` in [the librarian](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/master/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/WindowsPhone/Platform/Bookmarks/MvxWindowsPhoneLiveTileBookmarkLibrarian.cs).

---

If you want to use this existing sample service "as is", then the fields currently available in the metadata are:

```
        public Uri BackgroundImageUri { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public Uri BackBackgroundImageUri { get; set; }
        public string BackTitle { get; set; }
        public string BackContent { get; set; }

        public int Count { get; set; }
```

but these fields are admittedly currently very WP7 specific - e.g. I doubt the image Uri's will be very reusable across different platforms.

---

At a practical level, when I develop anything which requires a lot of customisation of the live tile - e.g. downloaded Images - then I normally build a new simple BookmarkLibrarian service based on the existing code, and this customised code sits in the WP7 UI code for that project (and is interface injected into the ViewModel)

I find this customised approach makes the bookmark API much simpler, and it allows me to write the WP7-specific logic within the WP7 application project (rather than in the shared core project).

---

The key to writing a custom bookmark service is to understand how the navigation uri is generated in [1](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/master/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/WindowsPhone/Platform/Bookmarks/MvxWindowsPhoneLiveTileBookmarkLibrarian.cs) - see the code near `GetXamlUriFor` - the uri is created by serializing an `MvxShowViewModelRequest` and adding a query parameter which indicates the unique name for this bookmark.

---

When you've added a bookmark in this way, then you can adjust your "normal" start navigation code in the WP7 App.xaml.cs to something like:

```
        RootFrame.Navigating += (innerSender, args) =>
            {
                if (!_firstNavigation)
                    return;
                _firstNavigation = false;

                var applicationStart = this.GetService<IMvxStartNavigation>();
                if (args.Uri.ToString().Contains("MainPage.xaml")
                    || !applicationStart.ApplicationCanOpenBookmarks)
                {
                    args.Cancel = true;
                    RootFrame.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(applicationStart.Start);
                }
            };
```

This code allows bookmarks to be opened directly.

---

If you ever need to run any code (e.g. an agent) to update the tile to make it "live" then you'll have to do this yourself - I'm afraid there aren't any samples available right now... although I have used Mvx in non-UI projects now in both Android and WP7 - so I know it can be done!

Comment: thanks for answer, but what's next?
Secondary tile still navigate on MasterView, DetailViewModel have detailId parameter in constructor...

Comment: Updated - sorry again (it's not something I've done for a couple of months!)